# Menu dropdowns need to be above the content, not move content down

Tags: css

Ok so I am really new to CSS and have been using it quite a bit daily to get desired effects on sites.  I am working on a new menu, and I am using a preconfigured stack to show hidden content when the `li` is `mouseover`.  The issue is that I want the dropdown to be on top of the existing content and not drop the content down to reveal the dropdown menus.  I have achieved this on a full CSS menu, but this will not work here on this menu.  My dropdowns are this;

```
.drop_6 {
  width: 500px; 
  text-align:center;
padding: 4px 10px 4px 10px;
margin-right:30px;
margin-top:7px;
border:none;    
position: relative;
top: -18px;
right: -370px;


/* Rounded Corners */  
  -moz-border-radius: 0px 5px 5px 5px;  
  -webkit-border-radius: 0px 5px 5px 5px;  
 border-radius: 0px 5px 5px 5px;  


/* Background color and gradients */

  background: #b5f0ff;
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #b5f0ff, #009fc6);
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0% 0%, 0% 100%, from(#b5f0ff), to(#009fc6));
}
```

I tried making these `absolute` and the main content `relative`, but the jquery in this stack just does not like that at all, and I get no effect at all.  Here is a link to the mockup; http://testserver1.justrightwebdesign.com/

Answer (score 1):

- Get rid of `overflow: hidden` (.stacks_out, .stacks_top).
- Add `position: absolute` (.shell)
- Add `z-index: 1` (.shell)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [the z-index property](http://www.w3schools.com/CSSref/pr_pos_z-index.asp) in css.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you set overflow:hidden to many of the parent elements. Remove those and you should at least see some effects. Then apply position:absolute to the drop_X Elements and move them to the correct position with the top and left-attribues. You can also remove the margins since you can position them freely.